# How to make If Statement with ArrayList Contains (String and Integer )

Tags: java, android, android-studio, if-statement, arraylist

I want to put a conditional function that requires the amount of drug purchased to be 10 in order to allow them to place an order for other free drugs

**My Java Code**

```
  firestore.collection("Cart-"+  userid).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {


                for (DocumentSnapshot dsn: value.getDocuments()) {

                    Cart cart = dsn.toObject(Cart.class);

                    int total = cart.getPrice();

                    savetotalprice.add(total);


                    String productname= cart.getTitle();
                    int quantitycounter = cart.getQuantity();

                    if (quantitycounter >= 10 ){

                        freeorder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                    else if (quantitycounter <=9) {
                        freeorder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }


                    else {

                        neworder.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                      

                    }
                }
```

I saw a lot of Developers recommending an **arraylist <String , Int >** but how with **IF statement**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've shown seems irrelevant to the question you're asking. If you want the drug quantity to be at least 10, you have to check that before the data gets pushed to the backend.

so, everytime a user adds an item to cart, you do this:

```
if(cart.quantity < 10){
    toast("The minimum quantity allowed for a free item is 10")
}else{
    addItemToCart(item)
}
```

As for searching an item in an ArrayList, all you needed to do was google 'Search ArrayList Java' and you would have found the help you needed. You really rarely need to ask a new question on StackOverFlow.

To check if an item exists in an ArrayList, there are several ways:
Lets suppose:

```
ArrayList<String> aList= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
```

Then you can check if an element exists using following methods:

**1 - `Contains()`**

```
 if(aList.contains("A")){
   // "A" exists in the list
 }else{
  //"A" doesn't exist in the list
 }
```

**2 - `IndexOf()`**

```
 //This will return the index of the element you're looking for
 if(aList.indexOf("A") > -1){
   //"A" exists 
 }else{//"A" doesn't exist}
```

**3 - Basic Looping**

You can also use a for each loop to see if an array contains something

```
for(item in aList){
 if(item == "A"){
   return true;
 }
}
return false;
```

**4  - `Iterator()`**

You can also use an `Iterator` to traverse a collection

```
Iterator<String> iterator = aList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String value = iterator.next();
        if (value == "A") {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
```

**5  - `Stream API`**
Stream API allows you to use advanced filters.

```
String item = aList.stream().filter(item -> item == "A").findAny().orElse(null)
```

Reference : [Finding a list element in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/find-list-element-java)